# Change what Windows does when a drive is inserted

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, usb-storage

When you insert a drive--typically a USB thumb drive--Windows asks what you want to happen each time you insert it.  But once you've answered the question, you no longer have that choice.  Where is the setting to change this?

Answer (score 1):

For removable drives, you can right-click the drive, and there will be an option to "Open AutoPlay".  This does not cause it to "play" as the title suggests. It takes you to the original dialog you got the first time you inserted it.